# Cómo dar formato a los números de un input

Tags: javascript, php

Me gustaría  dar formato a un input en JavaScript. Lo que me muestra mi consulta es lo siguiente:
Tengo un resultado de: .026
Lo que quiero: 0.026
En mi base de datos mi procedure me da un resultado de 0.026 pero en mi input me muestra un .026

```js
function Buscar_CTSAdicional(id){
    $.ajax({
        "url":"../controller/datos/controlador_buscar_CTSAdicional.php",
        type:'POST',
        data:{
            id:id
        }
    }).done(function(resp){
       /*  alert(resp); */
        let data = JSON.parse(resp);
        if(data.length>0){
            document.getElementById('txtcstadiocinal').value =data[0][0] ;
            document.getElementById('txtcstadiocinalunit').value = data[0][1] ;
        }else{
            document.getElementById('txtcstadiocinal').value = "" ;
            document.getElementById('txtcstadiocinalunit').value = "" ;
        }
    })
}
```

```html
<label>Costos Adicionales UNIT.</label>
  <input type="text"  id="txtcstadiocinalunit" class="float-sm-right" size=40 style="width:100px" placeholder=".026" disabled>
```

Comment: ejem... ¿tienes algun especial interes en colgar esta pregunta en inglés o es que te has equivocado de sitio?  Si la dejas así te la cerraran aquí.

Comment: Gracias , me confundí

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es convertir el resultado que obtienes de tu API a un numero, ya que es texto, asi:

```js
document.getElementById('txtcstadiocinal').value = Number(data[0][0]);
document.getElementById('txtcstadiocinalunit').value = Number(data[0][1]);
```

Es posible que tengas que hacer algunas validaciones antes, ya que:

```js
Number(.026) // Devuelve 0.026 (number)
Number('.026') // Devuelve 0.026 (number)
Number(null) // Devuelve 0 (number)
Number(undefined) // Devuelve NaN
Number('') // Devuelve 0
```

**UPDATE**:

En vez de `Number` puedes usar `parseFloat` dependiendo de tu usecase. Ojo que tiene un comportamiento un poco diferente a `Number`:

```js
parseFloat(.026) // Devuelve 0.026 (number)
parseFloat('.026') // Devuelve 0.026 (number)
parseFloat(null) // Devuelve NaN
parseFloat(undefined) // Devuelve NaN
parseFloat('') // Devuelve NaN
```

Comment: La respuesta con number esta bien pero el resultado me sale 0.02624, como podría mostrar un resultado de  0.026

Comment: Puedes usar `.toFixed(3)` para eso, por ejemplo, `Number(value).toFixed(3)` para 3 decimales. Ojo que `toFixed` va a convertir el valor a `string`, si lo quieres como numero, vas a tener que convertirlo de vuelva.

Comment: muchas gracias.